# CDN caching my HTML pages too!

Tags: seo, cache, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Recently I started using Amazon CloudFront to serve my site's JS,CSS and images via CDN. However, seems like with those, CloudFront serving my HTML pages as well? Thus `http://mydomain.com` and `http://cdn.mydomain.com` returning same result.

Will it hurt my site SEO in any way? How can I disable/tell CloudFront to exclude these HTML pages?

Comment: Caching HTML is a good thing a good thing. You should be able to set the cache time depending how often you update pages. If your update every hour then set the expiry to one hour, if its weekly then set it weekly ;)

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it will no hurt your SEO if your HTML page are static. The CDN will check for new versions from time to time (it depends on the configuration).

If your pages are not static, then you may want to set a `no-cache` header to your html pages. The CDN will not store a copy and users will always get a fresh version. If you don't do this, your users may have a bad experience and decide not to return to your site. So, this could impact your SEO indirectly.